# How to calculate a process time?

Tags: java

I have a batch process that take a file, read the lines and transform them in information for another process, this process is pretty long. For review information, I want to calculate how long it take for process a file, How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Find the amount per second a file is being processed, find the total amount of the file, then divide the file by the processed amount per second and the number is how many seconds it is estimated to take for the whole task

Comment: You need to tell us more: do you have access to the code, or do you just want to time how long it takes for your process to run once?  If the latter, are you on Windows?  Linux?  Solaris?

Comment: @SamSanjabi, I only want how can I calculate the time.

Comment: @Moises Gil, Before or after the process is complete?

Comment: When it is completed for know how time it consumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get current time in milliseconds. So take it when start processing and when finish and calculate the difference.

Comment: I think he means an estimated time when the process starts

Comment: The problem of this approach is that the CPU may be busy computing on other processes while running the program. So this way isn't an exact solution for processing time

Answer (score 0):

Each second (or any constant amount of time), record which percentage of the file you have processed since the last second.

This well give you % per second, a measure of how fast the process is working.

You can then remember the last 5 values of this number (to remove random spikes and such), calculate their average, and then approximate **total time remaining** based on the remaining percentage.

Display that number to the user.

So if your speed is 0.5%/s, and you have 25% of the input left to process, the time remaining is 50 seconds.

Of course, you can use bytes instead of percentages, or a different time constant instead of one second.